# Calling function inside of an interval causes "Uncaught TypeError: this._FunctionName is not a function" in my JS file

Tags: javascript, magento2

I am trying to set an interval in my JS file and call a function from within it. However, I get an error when trying to call a function from inside of the interval. Here is my code:

Note: I trigger `_testFunction()` to start the chain at the top of the document.

```
_testFunction3: function(){
    console.log("Test Function 3 Hit");
},
_testFunction2: function(){
    console.log("Test Function 2 Hit");
},
_testFunction: function(){
    console.log("Test Function 1 Hit");
    this._testFunction2();
    var timer = null;
    timer = setInterval(function(){
        this._testFunction3();
    }, 1000);
},
```

**Expected result:**

*Console logging following:*

- Test Function 1 Hit
- Test Function 2 Hit
- Test Function 3 Hit (every 1 second)

**Actual result:**

*Console logging following:*

- Test Function 1 Hit
- Test Function 2 Hit
- Uncaught TypeError: this._testFunction3 is not a function

I have tried many things and just can't get it to work...

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you?

```js
function _testFunction3() {
    console.log("Test Function 3 Hit");
}
function _testFunction2() {
    console.log("Test Function 2 Hit");
}
function _testFunction() {
    console.log("Test Function 1 Hit");
    this._testFunction2();
    var timer = null;
    timer = setInterval(this._testFunction3,  1000);
}
_testFunction();
```

I think part of the problem was that defining functions like `_function: function(){}` must be invalid.

(Note: while debugging, I got a different error, "Function statements require a function name").